# Defining the differentiation operator

Tags: functions, derivatives

The differentiation operator is the function $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}: f \mapsto f'$. My question is, does the operator really take an entire function $f$ as an argument? For example, when differentiating, it is usually always essential that one has some kind of algebraic or analytical expression, $f(x)$; e.g., let $f(x) = 5x^2 + 1$, then $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(5x^2 + 1) = 10x$. But as is known, $f(x)$ is not a function, it is simply the image of $x$ under $f$. Therefore, wouldn't it be more appropriate to define the differentiation operator as $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}: f(x) \mapsto f'(x)$?

EDIT: If $f(x)$ is, as some of you say, shorthand for $f: x \mapsto f(x)$ Then how do I interpret $\int f(x)~dx$? I thought that this was supposed to mean that we sum all of the infinitesimal rectangles, where $f(x)$ is the function value?

Comment: You are not interpreting the equation as it should be. It *is* a functional equation. The expressions $5x^2 + 1$ and $10x$ in the equation stand for the functions $x \mapsto 5x^2 + 1$ and $x \mapsto 10x$ resp., *not* real values for an unspecified $x$ as you seem to think.

Comment: Well, if you really want to get it correct, let *I* be a fixed open interval in $\mathbb {R},$ let $\cal D$ be the set of functions from $I$ to $\mathbb R$ that have a finite two-sided derivative at each point of $I,$ and let $\Delta'$ be the set of finite two-sided derivative functions from $I$ to ${\mathbb R}$ (thus, $\Delta'$ is a proper subset of the Darboux Baire $1$ functions from $I$ to ${\mathbb R}).$ Then $\frac{d}{dx}:{\cal D} \rightarrow {\Delta'}$ is the function defined by $\frac{d}{dx}(f) = f'.$ Or something like this $\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

No, differentiation is an operation on functions, it cannot be defined for individual function values. That is $f(x)=g(x)$, for some particular $x$, does not imply $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for that $x$. It is actually a fairly complicated definition: to define a single value of $f'$, you need to know values of$~f$ in a whole neighbourhood of $x$, and hope that a certain limit exists. Then to define $f'$ ou need to do that whole process for many values of $x$, hope that the definition works out each time, and combine all the resulting values to a new function that is called $f'$. Formally one could define
$$
  D: f\mapsto f'=\left(x\mapsto \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\right)
$$
It is actually pretty amazing this works so often, and gives a pleasant function as a result.

In fact, and here we approach the true difficulty, that it works so often is because in practice we apply this operation *only* to a very small class of pathologically well-behaved functions, those for which arbitrary function values that can be specified by a fairly simple expression of the function argument, i.e., those that if we call them $f$ can be specified by requiring $f(x)=E$ for all $x$, where $E$ is some expression (probably) involving a variable$~x$. [Side note: many would avoid the latter phrase, instead writing $E(x)$ in place of$~E$, but doing so makes $E$ a *function* rather than an expression, in fact $E=f$ so it is rather pointless.] Even though this class is very tiny with respect to that of functions for which the differentiation as given above is defined, it provides the overwhelming majority of cases that occur in concrete examples, for the simple reason that concretely describing functions $f$ for which $f(x)$ is not at all described by an expression involving $~x$ is extremely difficult, if not impossible.

As we all have learned, if it is given that $f(x)=E$ for all $x$, the one can (usually) find an expression specifying the values $f'(x)$ of the derivative by some formal manipulations of the expression $E$. In this situation the whole definition of differentiation disappears from view, and one can read $f'(x)$ as standing for the expression in$~x$ so obtained from$~E$. This is the situation where the notation $\def\d{\mathrm d}\frac\d{\d x}$ makes most sense: it is a formal operation on expressions, that transforms $E$ into the expression describing $f'(x)$, so that you can write $f'(x)=\frac\d{\d x}(E)$, or if you prefer $f':x\mapsto\frac\d{\d x}(E)$. From this point of view writing $\frac\d{\d x}(5x^2 + 1) = 10x$ is entirely correct and consistent.

---

N.B. The notation "$f(x)$" should *never* be used as shorthand for $x\mapsto f(x)$, because that is precisely what "$f$" already denotes; the least thing one could ask for a shorthand is that is not unnecessarily long.